# More than one exception when using the match operator

Tags: powershell, match, powershell-2.0

I have this part of my code:

```
$exception = "VM"

ForEach($item in $list) {

IF ($item -match $exception) { $invalidlist += $item }
ELSE { $validlist += $item }

}
```

Which works as intendet when only assigned 1 item to the variable `$exception`.
The Problem is, i need the variable to contain more then one item, like:`$exception = "VM","TM","TMP"`

How is it possible to search for a match to any item in `$exception`?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The `$list` is created by using:

`$list = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 548.00:00:00`

Comment: change to: `IF ($exception -match $item)`

Comment: Match is an array operator. When used in the way Avshalom described it will return all the objects that match. Returning any object will be evaluated as True

Comment: It doesn't work, did i maybe assign the variables to `$exception` (see above) wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your updated comment, your `$list` is array of AD Objects:
Assuming you care of the computer name, You should add the Name property to `$item` -> `$item.name` like in the following example:

*If you care to return only the Computer name and not the full object, add the $item.name to the invalid variable as well, e.g. `$invalidlist += $item.name`

```
$invalidlist = @()
$validlist = @()
$exception = "VM","TM","TMP"
$list = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 548.00:00:00   

ForEach($item in $list) {

## if the item in $exception are equal to the $item name you can use the contains operator
## otherwise you can use -match
IF ($exception -contains $item.name) { $invalidlist += $item }
ELSE { $validlist += $item }
}
```

Comment: logically this works, but for my case it doesnt.
The items matching the exceptions still get put into the validlist :/

Comment: ok after further testing i can confirm that your method works correctly when the `$list` array is filled like that example.

My `$list` is created by this code `$list = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 548.00:00:00`

why does it not work when `$list` is created this way? any idea how to correct that?
Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: You should add this kind of information to the question in the first place, Updated the answer..